# Are there any Workload Management subsystems for Linux?

Tags: linux, kernel, scheduling

Asked this on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/87893/are-there-any-workload-management-subsystems-for-linux), got no response:

Can anyone tell me of the status/state of WLM (Workload Management) kernel scheduler systems in Linux?  Alternatively, any user-space process goal-based load management programs?

This is a good start, but I'm not aware if these proposals are implemented?

http://www.computer.org/plugins/dl/pdf/proceedings/icac/2004/2114/00/21140314.pdf

http://ckrm.sourceforge.net/downloads/ckrm-linuxtag04-paper.pdf

AIX has inclusive WLM, anything comparable for Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very sure, but the closest I can think of is [cgroups](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt):

> Control Groups provide a mechanism for aggregating/partitioning sets of
>   tasks, and all their future children, into hierarchical groups with
>   specialized behaviour.

For more information, see one of:

- [Arch Wiki page for cgroups](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cgroups)
- [Wikipedia cgroups page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups)
- [RedHat cgroups page.](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/ch01.html)

Comment: This looks really good and actually answered a few of my `cgroups` questions.  Thanks,

Comment: No problem, glad I helped.

Comment: Neither of the links work anymore. I recommended deletion, but maybe the author is willing to make it an answer again.

Answer (score 3):

I'm looking at this one:

> `Slurm` is an open-source workload manager designed for Linux clusters of all sizes. It provides three key functions. First it allocates exclusive and/or non-exclusive access to resources (computer nodes) to users for some duration of time so they can perform work. Second, it provides a framework for starting, executing, and monitoring work (typically a parallel job) on a set of allocated nodes. Finally, it arbitrates contention for resources by managing a queue of pending work.

Refer to [`Slurm` Workload Manager](http://slurm.schedmd.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Portable Batch System [PBS Professional](https://pbspro.atlassian.net/) is something you can try. It comes in two flavors, one is Open Source and another commercial.
You can download the source from [here](https://github.com/PBSPro/pbspro) which also includes Installation instructions to help you in setting it up.

Answer (score 0):

I think `nq` is the tool you are looking for: https://github.com/leahneukirchen/nq . It's a lightweight job queue system without background daemons. And there are other tools mentioned by the author of `nq`, include `at`, `batch` and `task-spooler` with similar usages.